# Easiest way to recommend users to upgrade their browser?

Tags: browser, upgrade

There have been a lot of buzz around [IE6NoMore](http://www.ie6nomore.com/) campaign.
What's the easiest way to recommend users to upgrade their browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use conditional comments targeting IE. This way other browsers/bots (even when masquerading as IE) won't see it.

Make sure the message is polite and unobtrusive. Focus on benefits of change ("our website is faster and easier to use in up-to-date browsers") rather than negative aspects of IE (otherwise users could interpret this as ridicule of them or anti-Microsoft fanboyism).

Be as non-technical as possible. [Average user doesn't know the difference between Internet, browser and search engine](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4MwTvtyrUQ) (← this video is painful to watch).

Comment: Not painful, reality. People drive in cars without any knowledge of the engine, they expect the same from the computer. The big question is who's to blame... but that is a completely different discussion.

Answer (score 3):

You can recommend things to people until you're blue in the face, but the reason people who don't instinctively upgrade their browser actually get around to doing it will always be the same. They do it because there's something they want to use, but can't unless they upgrade.

Want people to quit using an old browser ?
Quit supporting it.
It's that simple.

Answer (score 1):

If no one supported them anymore then you wouldn't have to write code for them.  For a certain percentage of people, they upgrade through necessity, not out of choice.  If IE6 keeps working then they will keep using.  Dont make the extra effort to support IE6.

Answer (score 0):

From a psychological point of view, users will upgrade software due to one of the following reasons:
 - Need (they have to have feature)
 - Benefit (they'd like to have a feature)
 - Fear (they perceive some sort of damage if they don't have a feature)

Based on how well you know your users, you can use one of these approaches to motivate them to upgrade. I.e., Provide extra functionality in your software that works only in new browsers (suggestion: use Ajax for better page update, without the need to call another page or refresh the current). Make those users aware that new, better, safer functionality is available, if they just upgrade their browser.

But remember the following caveats:

1. Not everyone can upgrade on his own. OS and browser versions are often dictated by IT policies in medium-large organizations.
2. Not everyone is tech-savvy enough to upgrade - you may need to explain the process.
3. If the user can dictate behavior, he may require you to provide the shiny new functionality in the old browser - be careful how you present those benefits!

Answer (score 0):

The type of people who haven't yet upgraded their browser will almost certainly be people who don't have the technical knowledge to do so; those users who do know what a browser is, does and how to upgrade (and the benefits of upgrading) will most probably have done so. From this you can see how important it is to explain clearly and concisely both the benefits of upgrading and precisely how to do so for those who aren't technically minded.